# dealing with missing values input file

Tags: input, sas, file-io

I need to input a database with delimiter dlm="*" like this:

```
Abatucci Pierre*Derniers rayons*1200*1*55*84*5
Abatucci Pierre*L'entrée au château*1000*1*75*91
```

and it works fine like this:

```
Data  ProjSas.Artiste1;
Infile "C:\Users\Gila\Desktop\StatOrdinL2020\artiste1.txt" dlm="*";
    LENGTH Artiste $ 25 titre $30;                  
Input Artiste $ Titre  Prix  Deces  Hauteur   Largeur  Medium;
      Run;
```

but in some entries I have missing values like this...(after the 7000)

```
Beauquesne Wilfrid*Combat d'escorte dans les rues de Verdun*7000**82*100*5
```

so that value is skipped and the 82 is put in the wrong place and so are the following values.

Answer (score 2):

Add the DSD option to your INFILE statement [(How do I read a delimited file in SAS?)](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/faq/readdsd.htm)

```
Infile "C:\Users\Gila\Desktop\StatOrdinL2020\artiste1.txt" dlm="*" DSD;
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can just use proc import if you already have column names included in the source text file

```
proc import datafile="C:\Users\Gila\Desktop\StatOrdinL2020\artiste1.txt"
 out=ProjSas.Artiste1 dbms=dlm;
 delimiter='*';
 getnames=yes;
  run;
```